# Issue with imwheel config file and thumb buttons

Tags: mouse, logitech, mouse-wheel

I'm on ubuntu 22.04 LTS and have been having issues with my thumb buttons not being detected even after trying imwheel -b "45" command as recommended in other posts.
Right now I have a mousewheel.sh file that looks like this:

```
### see if imwheel config exists, if not create it ###
if [ ! -f ~/.imwheelrc ]
then

cat >~/.imwheelrc<<EOF
".*"
None,      Up,   Button4, 4
None,      Down, Button5, 4
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5

EOF

fi
##########################################################

CURRENT_VALUE=$(awk -F 'Button4,' '{print $2}' ~/.imwheelrc)

NEW_VALUE=$(zenity --scale --window-icon=info --ok-label=Apply --title="Wheelies" --text "Mouse wheel speed:" --min-value=1 --max-value=100 --value="$CURRENT_VALUE" --step 1)

if [ "$NEW_VALUE" == "" ];
then exit 0
fi

sed -i "s/\($TARGET_KEY *Button4, *\).*/\1$NEW_VALUE/" ~/.imwheelrc # find the string Button4, and write new value.
sed -i "s/\($TARGET_KEY *Button5, *\).*/\1$NEW_VALUE/" ~/.imwheelrc # find the string Button5, and write new value.

cat ~/.imwheelrc
imwheel -kill
```

And here is the .imwheelrc:

```
".*"
None,      Up,   Button4, 5
None,      Down, Button5, 5
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

I have tried running imwheel -d --debug --kill, and strangely enough that is the only place my mouse thumb buttons are detected, yet they print out "[" and "]" respectively.
Can someone please help me figure out how to get my mouse buttons to work, as I am brand new to Linux and am a bit lost right now. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable back/forward thumb buttons for all applications with:

```
None,      Thumb1, Alt_L|Left
None,      Thumb2, Alt_L|Right
```

So please clean the .imwheelrc file and add the below config to this file:

```
".*"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
None,      Thumb1, Alt_L|Left
None,      Thumb2, Alt_L|Right
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

You will be able to use these mouse actions input:
Up, Down, Left, Right, Thumb

It will fix your problem.